# thymeleaf: Static resources are not loading in while using layouts

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

My directory structure is

**Directory structure**

```
src/
  main/
    resources/
        static/
             CSS/
             JS/
             images/

        template/
           fragments/
                         header.html
                         footer.html
                         navBar.html
            layouts/
                         appLayout.html
                         baseLayout.html
                 welcome.html
```

**appLayout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" 
      href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" 
      th:href="@{/bootstrap.min.css}" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" 
      href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" 
      th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" 
      href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" 
      th:href="@{css/bootstrap.min.css}" />


   <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>
<body>

<div th:replace="/fragments/header :: header"></div>
<div th:replace="/fragments/navbar :: navbar"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div layout:fragment="content">
    <p>Content goes here...</p>
    </div>
    <footer>
    <div th:replace="/fragments/footer :: footer"></div>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please do check the `<links>` tag in above layout, I have used different locations to the link tag, none giving the `404 error` why is it so?

[image]

Please look the above image, I have css and js files in resources/static/css/ folder and JS is int /resources/static/js/ folder what is going wrong? why isn't chrome showing 404 error for some static resources?

Comment: Can you give an specific example where you expect an error?

Comment: `bootstrap.min.css` is in `static/css/` so other linked resources should show 404 error on chrome devtool.

Comment: did you add custom resourcehandlers?

Comment: No. I'm using spring boot's default settings

Comment: Have you mapped welcome.html by a controller? If not add a controller to map your URL of the HTML page

Comment: Obviously man. Controller's request handling method is redirecting me to the welcome.html.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Can you post a GitHub link to a small project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: here is the github link https://github.com/PieChuckerr/gateApp

Comment: @punkrocker27ka check the git repo link. you can pull and directly run the app.

Comment: @piechuckerr Thanks.  I've answered the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43326491/1078565

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bootstrap CSS and JS network requests are returning 200 because the response is successful, however the contents are not what you're expecting.  If you look into the response you'll see that for every CSS and JS request, it is returning the HTML page welcome.html.

This is because your Controller mapping is overriding the resource requests. You're using the `name` parameter for the mapping which isn't the correct attribute.  Use `value` instead, e.g:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

This change will result in your CSS and JS requests returning 404's.  This is progress.

Also, remove your `MvcConfig` as this behavior is provided out of the box.

Finally, adjust the path to your resources like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
```

Now the CSS and JS requests will return successfully with the appropriate content.

Comment: The name is used as an identifier for the mapping.  But value is used for matching a URL pattern (e.g. "/", "/**", "/home", "/about", etc.) to a handler method (e.g. HomeController.gethomePage()).  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html

Comment: @KyleAnderson I've tried as many permutations of linking to my bootstrap files as I can think of, including the one from your answer. Do you know why else this might be returning a 404? I've used `value` for all of my mapping.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from your post is that you have a whole kind of static content like CSS files and js files, which are not getting served correctly when you change the paths of those links.

**In other words, when you change the paths of those links the behavior is not changing, and you're getting unexpected results.**

The solution to that, or the answer to your question, why I get that kind of behavior is fairly simple.

When you use **Spring boot** and try to serve **static content** your browser is caching your old behavior and old responses of older requests, **which means you need to bust the browser cache in order to get your expected result** when you change the links paths.

You can do it by adding the next configuration to your application.properties file:

```
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
```

you can find some more information on how to serve static content while using spring boot in their documentation here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: No need, check out my solution, I had your problem a few times and solved it after doing so + after a read Spring Documentation

Answer (score 0):

static is default resource mapping in springboot you not need to add static in resource path<

```
link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"rel="stylesheet"th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
```